# Why after i uninstall nvm, when i do 'npm install yarn -g', it still give nvm related info?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, nvm

I am using a MAC that i install nvm before. I have tried to uninstall nvm by following the link https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/298.

Afterward I thought i have clean environment of node and npm:

node -v
v8.11.3

npm -v
5.6.0

However when i try to install yarn globally by 'npm install yarn -g', the info message i get is:

/Users/Uxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin/yarnpkg -> /Users/Uxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/Users/Uxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin/yarn -> /Users/Uxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
+ yarn@1.19.1
added 1 package in 1.122s

I am really confused.

I've done removing nvm everywhere in .bash_profile, .bashsc, and removed ~/.nvm folder multiple times.

But why it looks like nvm is still here?

Comment: Did you remove the nvm command from .bash_profile or .profile and then closed the terminal an opened a new one?

Comment: @some yes, i remove all nvm keyword in those config files, and open a new terminal. Only thing i have not tried is reboot machine. But it should not matter i think.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience. I think the root cause is npm config is changed by nvm and prefix is set to ~/.nvm directory